# class implementing Parcelable

Tags: android, serialization

I want to pass a arraylist of a class from one activity to another.To do the same, the class is implementing Parcelable.The issue is few fields are null in the class.How to check and send only the values which are not null.I think this can be done easily by simple if/else in writeToParcel() but how to do the same in constructor of the class which takes parameter as Parcel. Like as follows

```
private Student(Parcel in) {
}
```

There are some issues while sending null values..

EDIT:Added code

```
    @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(grade);
            dest.writeString(dateOfBirth);
            dest.writeString(place);
                //Like wise there are many other fields
                //We have to write only values which are not null
}

       private Student(Parcel in) {
            id=in.readString();
            name=in.readString();
            grade=in.readString();
            dateOfBirth=in.readString();
            place=in.readString();
            //like wise have to read all other fields
           //we have to make sure we read only values which are not null
}
```

Comment: How come you are not implementing `Serializable` instead?

Comment: What you trying to achieve doesn't make any sense. You have already analysed your problem and encapsulated your domain object, think more in a OO way at student level. there is no need to care about and do special conditional code to the internal value in domain object from outside.

Comment: paste your code... it shouldn't be a problem to handle null values

Answer (score -1):

Simpest way is Create one Globalclass.java and declare static arraylist like public static `ArrayList<String> arrayList  = new ArrayList<String>();`
and when u want to use `Globalclass.arrayList = value`; and Use anyware in project.

Another way to pass using intent

```
Intent i =new Intent(this,2activity.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra(name, arrayList);
```

Comment: well i dont really want to create any static ArrayList which could eventually lead to memory crash in my project.ArrayList in my project may have upto 300 class objects.Each class have some 20 elements.So its not wise idea to create a static ArrayList.

Comment: Intent i =new Intent(this,2activity.class);i.putStringArrayListExtra(name, value);

Comment: Downvoted because of the global static variable. This has no use (`Intent`s are made to do this), and can only lead to crashes (what about your `Activity` being called from another one, with the static variable still `null`?)